# Vaccinations for the US

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, k1-visa

I received the second NOA (Notification of Action) for the fiancee visa process and I'm getting myself ready for my medical examination before the interview at the US consulate in London. I have a record of my vaccinations and just want to confirm what I will need.

1. I never had the MMR vaccination (Measles Mumps Rubella). I had Measles and Mumps diseases but not Rubella so I need to get vaccinated for the latter. Is it worth getting tested for Measles and Mumps antibodies (65£ for each test at Knightsbridge) to prove I don't need vaccines for these 2? Single vaccines for these are not sold separately anymore so I would probably need to get the MMR vaccine anyway, correct?
2. I never got vaccinated for Hepatitis A, Influenza, Meningococcal, Pneumococcal and Rotavirus. These vaccines are required [according to the US Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/vaccinations.html).

[According to the UK embassy](https://uk.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/11/vaccine_chart.pdf) you only need them if you're a child though. Do I need them since I never got them as a child?

- (I never had chickenpox and didn't get a vaccine so I will need to get it done in the US before AOS (adjustment of status) since that it's not sold in the UK).

  3. Is there a price list online for vaccines at Boots? I'm trying to find out if it's [cheaper than Knightsbridge](http://www.visamedicals.info/us-price.asp). I couldn't find the prices for Boots but other vendors have similar prices. Eg. http://www.nomadtravel.co.uk/pg/42/VaccinationPrices

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answers got on a forum:

1. So I would probably need to get the MMR vaccine anyway, correct?

Yes. Easier. Cheaper.

2. I never got vaccinated for Hepatitis A, Influenza, Meningococcal, Pneumococcal and Rotavirus.

You only need the adult shots. Influenza is an adult shot. Skip the rest. You will pay a USCIS designated civil surgeon in the US to sign off on vaccinations since you will not have clearance on Varicella marked on your visa medical form. It's hard to find one who won't insist on doing the entire medical over again, even though USCIS accepts your visa medical for AOS.

(3. Call them)

Comment: Note that the varicella vaccination takes 2 shots spaced a month or two apart, so you need to have time for that. Since that is going to take time you might also consider the alternative of getting all of them done in the US. They can be done at a pharmacy in most states.

Comment: *Answers got on a forum* Reference?

Comment: It doesn't add much but here is the link: http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/611262-uk-vaccinations-for-k1/?page=2&tab=comments#comment-9031039

Comment: While the hepatitis series are normally given in childhood they certainly can be done in adulthood if you didn't get them earlier.  Plenty of us who were born before they were out got them as adults.